# What happens if my C# switch expression is non-exhaustive?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, switch-expression

In C# 8, switch expressions were introduced.  What happens if a switch expression is not exhaustive?  In other words, what happens if I don't test for every possible value?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = 1;
    int imExhaustive = x switch
    {
        3 => 4,
        _ => 0   // x = 1 matches this
    };
    int okFine = x switch
    {
        1 => 4   // x = 1 matches this
    };
    int noMatch = x switch
    {
        3 => 4   // No match
    };
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If the `switch` expression is not exhaustive, the compiler produces a warning.
At runtime, if you pass a value that is not handled, a `SwitchExpressionException` is thrown.

This is documented in the speclet for new patterns feature in C# 8.0: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-8.0/patterns.md#switch-expression

> The compiler shall produce a warning if it proves (using those
>   techniques) that some possible input value might not match some
>   switch_expression_arm at runtime.
>
> At runtime, the result of the switch_expression is the value of the
>   expression of the first switch_expression_arm for which the expression
>   on the left-hand-side of the switch_expression matches the
>   switch_expression_arm's pattern, and for which the case_guard of the
>   switch_expression_arm, if present, evaluates to true.
>
> If there is no
>   such switch_expression_arm, the switch_expression throws an instance
>   of the exception
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.SwitchExpressionException.

Comment: One can always make their switch expressions exhaustive with the default or '_' option.

Answer (score 1):

Depends.

If there's a match:  It matches, and everything is fine.

If there's no match:  A `SwitchExpressionException` is thrown.

Best practice seems to be to write exhaustive switch expressions.  If you don't, and nothing explodes, you might just be getting lucky.

The compiler will warn you if your switch expression is not exhaustive, but it's not an error and it'll compile and run anyway.

(Just ran into this, so thought I'd share - It's nowhere in the documentation yet, though C# 8 is still in Preview)

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove this warning, add a default expression.

```
   exception switch
    {
        ValidationException vExp => new ValidationErrorDetail
        {
            
        },
        ApiException apiExp => new ApiErrorDetail
        {
           
        },
        ProcessException pExp => new ErrorDetail
        {
           
        },
        _ => new ErrorDetail
        {

        }
    };
```

Add `_ =>` and Default Expression to be excuted.

Answer (score 0):

For the case of unnamed enum values, I consider C#'s behavior of throwing an exception correct and desirable. So I disable the warning in my .editorconfig:

```
[*.cs]
dotnet_diagnostic.CS8524.severity = none # The switch expression does not handle some values of its input type (it is not exhaustive) involving an unnamed enum value.
```